# how to drag and drop only using button not by whole row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-sortable

I am making a demo in which user can drag and drop the row.In my demo user hold row anywhere (from whole width of row) and drop in another position.I need to prevent that it only drag and drop when user in the area of button .If user want to drag the row it should hold the button area and drop anywhere .

I am creating the row after click the button .Now I want to prevent the drag and drop from whole width only in button area.

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/22/

```
$("#testCaseContainer").sortable({
          stop: function( event, ui ) {



          }
    }).disableSelection();
```

first create 2 or 3 row after clicking add button.

then it should drag and drop on button area.

Thanks

Comment: jQuery UI Sortable has a handle attribute that's supposed to be a selector to identify your object that initiates the drag and drop for the element. Have you tried using it?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FZQ8D/23/ <-- Really simple test using the `handle` attribute, but it doesn't work with buttons, since buttons aren't draggable objects, so I replaced with with an ugly span.

Comment: @scragar  did not tried .I don't know that also I am also using first time this js..can you use fiddle to make.so that i can understand better.

Comment: @scragar thanks for help ..can you give an link where is all api and event available..

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Do you still need help? If your problem is solved you should write an answer by yourself or delete this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @scragar given the perfect answer .

```
$("#testCaseContainer").sortable({
        handle: '.editButton',
          stop: function( event, ui ) {

                      var obj={};
        var len=$("#testCaseContainer > div").length;
    // alert("all Index");
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
           // var id=
      //alert($("#testCaseContainer > div").eq(i).find('li').attr('id'));
            obj[i]=$("#testCaseContainer > div").eq(i).find('li').attr('id');

          //  alert($("#testCaseContainer > div")[0].find('li').id);

        }
console.log(obj)  

          }
    }).disableSelection();
```